# AVAudioPlayerNode causing distortion

Tags: swift, macos, audio, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I have an `AVAudioPlayerNode` attached to an `AVAudioEngine`. Sample buffers are provided to `playerNode` via the `scheduleBuffer()` method.

However, it seems like `playerNode` is distorting the audio. Rather than simply "passing through" the buffers, the output is distorted and contains static (but is still mostly audible).

Relevant code:

```swift
let myBufferFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 48000, channels: 2)

// Configure player node
let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: myBufferFormat)

// Provide audio buffers to playerNode
for await buffer in mySource.streamAudio() {
    await playerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer)
}
```

In the example above, `mySource.streamAudio()` is providing audio in realtime from a ScreenCaptureKit `SCStreamDelegate`. The audio buffers arrive as `CMSampleBuffer`, are converted to `AVAudioPCMBuffer`, then passed along via `AsyncStream` to the audio engine above. I've verified that the converted buffers are valid.

Maybe the buffers don't arrive fast enough? This graph of ~25,000 frames suggests that `inputNode` is inserting segments of "zero" frames periodically:

[image]

The distortion seems to be a result of these empty frames.

### Edit:

Even if we remove `AsyncStream` from the pipeline, and handle the buffers immediately within the ScreenCaptureKit callback, the distortion persists. Here's an end-to-end example that can be run as-is (the important part is `didOutputSampleBuffer`):

```swift
class Recorder: NSObject, SCStreamOutput {
    
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    private let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    private var stream: SCStream?
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "sampleQueue", qos: .userInitiated)
    
    func setupEngine() {
        let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 48000, channels: 2)
        audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
        // playerNode --> mainMixerNode --> outputNode --> speakers
        audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: format)
        audioEngine.prepare()
        try? audioEngine.start()
        playerNode.play()
    }
    
    func startCapture() async {
        // Capture audio from Safari
        let availableContent = try! await SCShareableContent.excludingDesktopWindows(true, onScreenWindowsOnly: false)
        let display = availableContent.displays.first!
        let app = availableContent.applications.first(where: {$0.applicationName == "Safari"})!
        let filter = SCContentFilter(display: display, including: [app], exceptingWindows: [])
        let config = SCStreamConfiguration()
        config.capturesAudio = true
        config.sampleRate = 48000
        config.channelCount = 2
        stream = SCStream(filter: filter, configuration: config, delegate: nil)
        try! stream!.addStreamOutput(self, type: .audio, sampleHandlerQueue: queue)
        try! stream!.addStreamOutput(self, type: .screen, sampleHandlerQueue: queue) // To prevent warnings
        try! await stream!.startCapture()
    }
    
    func stream(_ stream: SCStream, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, of type: SCStreamOutputType) {
        switch type {
        case .audio:
            let pcmBuffer = createPCMBuffer(from: sampleBuffer)!
            playerNode.scheduleBuffer(pcmBuffer, completionHandler: nil)
        default:
            break // Ignore video frames
        }
    }
    
    func createPCMBuffer(from sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
        var ablPointer: UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>?
        try? sampleBuffer.withAudioBufferList { audioBufferList, blockBuffer in
            ablPointer = audioBufferList.unsafePointer
        }
        guard let audioBufferList = ablPointer,
              let absd = sampleBuffer.formatDescription?.audioStreamBasicDescription,
              let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: absd.mSampleRate, channels: absd.mChannelsPerFrame) else { return nil }
        return AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, bufferListNoCopy: audioBufferList)
    }
    
}

let recorder = Recorder()
recorder.setupEngine()
Task {
    await recorder.startCapture()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was the `createPCMBuffer()` function. Replace it with this and everything runs smoothly:

```swift
func createPCMBuffer(from sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
    let numSamples = AVAudioFrameCount(sampleBuffer.numSamples)
    let format = AVAudioFormat(cmAudioFormatDescription: sampleBuffer.formatDescription!)
    let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: numSamples)!
    pcmBuffer.frameLength = numSamples
    CMSampleBufferCopyPCMDataIntoAudioBufferList(sampleBuffer, at: 0, frameCount: Int32(numSamples), into: pcmBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList)
    return pcmBuffer
}
```

The original function in my question was taken directly from Apple's ScreenCaptureKit example project. It technically works, and the audio sounds fine when written to file, but apparently it's not fast enough for realtime audio.

**Edit:** Actually it's probably not about speed, as the new function is 2-3x slower on average due to copying data. It may have been that the underlying data was getting released when creating the `AVAudioPCMBuffer` with a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Write buffer to file: distorted!" block is almost certainly doing something slow and blocking (like writing to a file). You get called every 170ms (8192/48k). The tap block had better not take longer than that to execute, or you'll fall behind and drop buffers.

It is possible to keep up while writing to a file, but it depends on how you're doing this. If you're doing something very inefficient (like reopening and flushing the file for every buffer), then you're probably not keeping up.

If this theory is correct, then the live speaker output should not have static, just your output file.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not our culprit here. The live speaker output is also distorted, and removing the tap entirely makes no difference.

Comment: In that case, you're not scheduling your buffers fast enough, or you are starving the audio render thread (using all the cores for other things). I would first suspect the former. How are you ensuring that `streamAudio()` returns audio buffers before they are needed? The `for-await` loop is going to switch threads. What's the TaskPriority? Can this Thread ever starve? I think you may need to update the question to remove things that don't impact you (the tap), and add things that do (how are you generating this audio and ensuring that it is always scheduled on time?)

Comment: Thanks - I updated the question to explain the source of audio buffers. I think you may be right that the buffers aren't being scheduled fast enough - but what can be done when they're arriving in realtime? ScreenCaptureKit provides buffers with a length of 960 frames, which we schedule immediately (after conversion)  into `inputNode`. The tap spits out buffers of length 4800 at regular intervals, regardless of whether 4800 frames have actually arrived from our source.

Comment: I should mention the goal of this project: to mix the incoming live captured audio (from ScreenCaptureKit) with live microphone audio. I'm open to other methods, but AVAudioEngine seemed like the best way to do this. And AVAudioPlayerNode is the only way I know how to get external buffers into the engine...

Comment: If you're using ScreenCaptureKit, don't you get `didOutputSampleBuffer` callbacks? That's where you should be scheduling the buffer. Your code doesn't explain `streamAudio()`, which I expect is where your largest problems are. `for-await` is very likely putting a lot of non-deterministic delay into this, plus synchronization you don't want. (I'm not saying that async is slow or bad; but it's not really meant for real-time work, and this seems a particularly strange way to do it.)

Comment: Ok, I removed the AsyncStream and isolated the issue as much as possible. Please see my latest edit: this shows a complete example and should be reproducible. The buffers as scheduled into the engine directly from `didOutputSampleBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen the createPCMBuffer implementation return nil in certain cases, breaking our microphone audiowave code and ScreenCaptureKit audio recording implementation.

Seems like copying the unsafe pointer and using it outside the block you pass to withAudioBufferList isn't a good idea. We've adjusted our implementation to this, and that fixes the problems:

```
func createPCMBuffer(for sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
    try? sampleBuffer.withAudioBufferList { audioBufferList, _ -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? in
        guard let absd = sampleBuffer.formatDescription?.audioStreamBasicDescription else { return nil }
        guard let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: absd.mSampleRate, channels: absd.mChannelsPerFrame) else { return nil }
        return AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, bufferListNoCopy: audioBufferList.unsafePointer)
    }
}
```

This solution is closer to the original ScreenCaptureKit sample from Apple and should not have the performance hit Hundley is describing above.